# RSpec test PUT update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, crud, put

I am trying to write some RSpec tests to test my app, but I've stumbled on several problems that I can't find any solution.
1) I am trying to test the update action. Here is my code:

```
        it "email is a new one" do
            put :update, id: @user, user: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user, :email=>"a@b.c")
            @user.reload
            @user.email.should == "a@b.c"
            puts @user.email
        end
```

Here is the UsersController update action:

```
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to edit_user_path(@user), :notice => "Your settings were successfully updated."}
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is the error:

```
 Failure/Error: @user.email.should == "a@b.c"
       expected: "a@b.c"
            got: "user16@example.com" (using ==)
```

It's obvious that the test hasn't changed the email of the user.
I took the update action tutorial from here: http://everydayrails.com/2012/04/07/testing-series-rspec-controllers.html .
Where I could find the solution?

Comment: You're assigning the factory to the contact, not to the user... Is it meant to be that way?

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to change it. I've written and copied it several times in order to avoid typos. But the problem still exist.

Answer (score 5):

Could `@user.update_attributes(params[:user])` be failing for a validation reason?

Also, you could ensure that your test and the controller method are interacting with the same ruby object. That's been a gotcha for me in the past. The way I do it is to stub the `find` method on the class.

```
it "email is a new one" do
  User.stubs(:find).returns(@user)
  put :update, id: @user, user: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user, :email=>"a@b.c")
  @user.reload
  @user.email.should == "a@b.c"
  puts @user.email
end
```

This ensures that you're talking about not only the same record, but the same object during the test.

---

Lastly, I would argue that your test is doing very much for you. You're basically testing `update_attributes`, which is a core feature and thoroughly tested already. I would focus on testing the controller behavior. Something like this:

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

describe "PUT #update" do

  before(:each) {
    User.stubs(:find).returns(user)
  }

  it "should redirect to the user path on succesful save" do
    user.should_receive(:update_attributes).and_return true
    put :update, user, {}
    response.should redirect_to(edit_user_path(user))
  end

  it "should render the edit screen again with errors if the model doesn't save" do
    user.should_receive(:update_attributes).and_return false
    put :update, user, {}
    response.should render_template("edit")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the argument for `put` is incorrect.

`put`, `get`, `delete`, `post` accept three arguments. The first is path, second is params, and the third is options.

In you code you put two params as two arguments, it's incorrect.

```
put :update, id: @user, user: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user, :email=>"a@b.c")
```

So, change it to

```
put :update, {id: @user, user: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user, :email=>"a@b.c")}
```

But, wait! your code will work by above change, but there is security hole in your current code. Make sure you'll add authority check in controller code. For example

```
return unauthorized unless @user == current_user || current_user.role == "admin"
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try. And I've already fixed the security hole ;)